# How to make MVC4 web.api aplication referenced with ATL COM (dll) work on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dll, iis-7, com

I need my MVC4 web.api application to work with simple Com-object (ATL dll).
All works fine on development server but when I publish the project to local IIS I've got error message

Unable to get the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E3D8B330-0622-4857-99D2-A72EB7A4CDE3} due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I'd used regsvr32 to register my dll.
I even made sample console app that use same dll and all works fine in this way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can the test app run successfully using the credentials that IIS is running under?

If not, does the account IIS is running under have access to the registry key?

Is the app pool 32bit or 64bit; does it match the COM DLL?

Comment: I'm not sure I completly understand what you asking about:
what is test app (console app or web app on development iis)?

Comment: You said in your original question "I even made sample console app that use same dll and all works fine in this way." Can you log into the IIS machine using the same account that IIS is running under and then run the test app to see if it works?

Comment: IIS is running under System account. I'm not sure I'm able to launch my console app same way. Sorry if I'm wrong. P.S. all the things are happens on my local PC - I have Win7 with IIS7 installed and VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

It is required to build COM-object (dll) for x64 (see Project's properties in VS).
I have Win7 x64 installed so IIS runing on it is x64 too (I guess).